# How do I make the value text of input tag positioned in the upper left?

Tags: html, css

I made the input box bigger (like 500 by 500 pixels), but the text would start from the middle, not the top. I tried putting the padding to zero but it doesn't seem to work. This is under the form tag.
Here's my html code:

```
<form>
<input class="postbox" value="Hello."><br>
</form>
```

and this is my css code:

```
.postbox{
    padding:0;
    height:500;
    width:500;}
```

Comment: Why do you want a very tall **single line** input?

Comment: height:500;   width:500; - height:500px;   width:500px;

Comment: That's what `textareas`are for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you stretched the input-line to 500px, not the form.
As Alvaro Menéndez noticed, you might want to use a textarea, not an input.

Use something like

```
<form>
<textarea class="postbox" placeholder="Hello"></textarea><br>
</form>
<style>
.postbox {
  padding:0;
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
}
</style>
```

http://pascha.org/test/2.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do it, i have removed the height and padded the input out

```
.postbox{
    padding-bottom:450px;
    width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the padding-bottom property

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="test"/>
```

CSS

```
input {
   padding: 10px 10px 100px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/ko9ahz0L/